# WriteableBitmap render textblock with text trimming

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone

[image]

The goal is to render 2 lines of text with ... at end.  I think the issue is the height won't render at the size I tell it (see maxHeight=30, but actualHeight 82).

The "canvas" variable is a writeablebitmap.

I've tried a null transform, and wrapping the text in a constant height grid.

Interesting note, is that the width works here and appropriately wraps.

Comment: Can you show the full code of your example?

Answer (score 3):

The following works if run in the background agent, but it doesn't work 100% if run from the app.
I just wrap it in a grid and call arrange on the grid.

[image]

Comment: TextBlock width is very important. I got totally different images in design time and runtime until I set the width.